# Boolean algebra problem simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to simplify the following Boolean expression

$$xz + x'y + zy$$

and the solution said it was $xz + x'y$. How did they get this answer? Also, I found this on the MIT site.

Comment: Have you made truth tables?

Comment: no I have not made it

Comment: I suggest you do it

Comment: See Consensus Theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xz + x'y + zy=\\
xz + x'y + zy(1)=\\
xz + x'y + zy(x+x')=\\xz + x'y + zyx+zyx'=\\
(xz +  zyx)+( x'y +zyx')=
\\xz(1+y)+x'y(1+z)
$$ and you take over now